Reloading page issue on Selenium IDE
I was wondering if anyone knows how to set up tests in Selenium IDE using test suites so that it runs without reloading the page every time for each test.
I tried removing the open command from the second test but it still doesn't seem to work and it's actually not loading the page at all and just breaks the test.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
